# Why does `sym` need to be used in this case when using `rewriting`?

Tags: agda

Given the Peano definition of natural numbers:

```
data ℕ : Set where
  zero : ℕ
  suc  : ℕ → ℕ

_+_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
zero + n = n
(suc m) + n = suc (m + n)
```

We can prove by different methods the property `∀ (m : ℕ) → zero + m ≡ m + zero`.

For example:

```
comm-+₀ : ∀ (m : ℕ) → zero + m ≡ m + zero
comm-+₀ zero = refl
comm-+₀ (suc n) =
  begin
    zero + suc n
  ≡⟨⟩
    zero + suc (zero + n)
  ≡⟨⟩
    suc (zero + n)
  ≡⟨ cong suc (comm-+₀ n) ⟩
    suc (n + zero)
  ≡⟨⟩
    suc n + zero
  ∎
```

And more compactly:

```
comm-+₀ : ∀ (m : ℕ) → zero + m ≡ m + zero
comm-+₀ zero = refl
comm-+₀ (suc n) = cong suc (comm-+₀ n)
```

If we want, we can even use `rewrite` and forgo `cong`:

```
comm-+₀ : ∀ (m : ℕ) → zero + m ≡ m + zero
comm-+₀ zero = refl
comm-+₀ (suc n) rewrite comm-+₀ n = refl
```

But wait! That doesn't work. Agda will tell us that the expression is wrong because it can't prove the following:

```
suc (n + 0) ≡ suc (n + 0 + 0)
```

If we present Agda the symmetrical rewrite of the property, `sym (comm-+₀ n)`, it will type check without errors.

So, my question is: why do we need `sym` in this case? The proof worked perfectly fine without it with the other strategies. Does rewrite work on both sides simultaneously and not just the left side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every cases, the goal when `m` is of the form `suc n` is:

```
suc n ≡ suc (n + 0)
```

To solve this goal by providing a correctly typed term, the right way is, as you noticed:

```
cong suc (comm-+₀ n)
```

However, when using `rewrite` with an equality `a ≡ b` you modify directly the goal by substituting **all occurences** of `a` by `b` In your case, using `rewrite` on the quantity `comm-+₀ n` whose type is `n ≡ n + 0` leads to the replacing of every occurence of `n` by `n + 0`, thus transforming the goal from

```
suc n ≡ suc (n + 0)
```

to

```
suc (n + 0) ≡ suc (n + 0 + 0)
```

which is not what you want to do. Since rewriting replaces all occurences of the left side by the right side, reversing the equality using `sym` will instead replace the only occurence of `n + 0` by `n` thus transforming the goal from

```
suc n ≡ suc (n + 0)
```

to

```
suc n ≡ suc n
```

which is your expected behaviour and let you conclude using `refl` direcly. This explains why you need to use `sym`.

---

To summarize :

- `rewrite` interacts directly with the type of the goal.
- `rewrite` rewrites from left to right.
- `rewrite` rewrites all occurences it finds in the type of the goal.

---

More on `rewrite` can be found here:

https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.0.1/language/with-abstraction.html#with-rewrite